# 3d object error once the model start running

Tags: anylogic

i am trying to use one of the 3d Objects in Anylogic , once i drag the item , it doesn't show the real shape of the object upon running and it shows the following [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRjjF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check on the resources section of your project if they are actually there... sometimes you move the .alp somewhere else and you lose the location of the objects... or sometimes AnyLogic just makes our life difficult

[image: resources]

if you have issues with the elements, you will see a red or grey circle instead of green.